# My Java polygon is not drawing, despite having seemingly valid vertex coordinates

Tags: java, swing

My teacher is having us write code to draw a logo on the screen using awt, swing, and the graphics class. I decided to draw the google drive symbol, but I am getting stuck on the yellow third.

```
public class DriveLogo extends JApplet
{
    public void init()
    {
        JRootPane rootPane = this.getRootPane();    
        rootPane.putClientProperty("defeatSystemEventQueueCheck", Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        int num_rect_points = 4;

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getSize().width, getSize().height);

        /*************************************Yellow 1/3**********************************/
        //Order of vertices: Left, right, lower-right, lower-left
        int p1x1 = 150, p1x2 = 250, p1x3 = 350, p1x4 = 300;

        int p1y1 = 25, p1y2 = 25, p1y3 = 280, p1y4 = 280;

        int[] poly_1_x = {
            p1x1, p1x2, p1x3, p1x4
        };

        int[] poly_1_y = {
            p1y1, p1y2, p1y3, p1y4
        };

        Polygon yellow = new Polygon(poly_1_x, poly_1_y, num_rect_points);


    /*************************************Draw**********************************/

        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillPolygon(yellow);
    }
}
```

This produces the following result:

[image]

There should be a yellow rhombus/rectangle slanted to the left. I asked my teacher, and she reviewed my code, but could not isolate the problem, and told me it "should" be working. Should doesn't mean it is however, and this is a rather large grade. Spent most of two class periods and downloaded the project to my home computer to debug, but I just can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Things I know; the polygon coordinates must be in order, so to draw a rectangle, I cannot list them top-left, bottom-right, bottom-left, top-right, but I can list them top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.

Comment: Custom painting should be done by overriding paintComponent() not paint(). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples. We don't know the context of how your code is executed so if you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Post the code for your entire class.  A common mistake is to extend Frame or JFrame, while having your `main` method create and display a new JFrame which is not an instance of your class.

Comment: @VGR No, my bad. I am extending JApplet and doing all of my drawing directly as it would only complicate it and add boilerplate to use the usual OOP approach for such a small project.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan, `Better?` -  No not really because you didn't take any time to read the link and structure your code properly. You learn by doing things properly, not by taking short cuts that will cause problems later when the code gets more complicated. In any case the posted code works fine for me using the appletviewer on JDK8 on Windows 7. By the way I would drop any course that uses Applets since they are no longer supported in most browsers.

Comment: @camickr Actually I fail to see how this code is improperly formatted...seems fine to me. And to address the edited post in regards to the linked article; Short - the example is trimmed down,  Self-contained - everything needed to run the code is included in the example saving imports, Correct - I do not see any syntax errors or really any errors. Thanks for the advice :-)

Comment: @DJMethaneMan, You did NOT read the tutorial on "Custom Painting" . Your painting code is NOT correct. Your Applet code is NOT correct.  The tutorials show you the proper way to do painting and even though you should NOT be using Applets, the tutorial also shows the proper way to code a JApplet.

Comment: Your code works for me as well.  Perhaps you should edit your question and include the HTML in which your applet is embedded.  And if you’re testing it with a particular browser, I would definitely try a different browser.

Comment: @camickr Well, I was told to override `paint` by my teacher. So I did everything correctly, at least in the context in which I was doing it. I DID read the tutorial, which said nothing about JApplets specifically, just about painting with swing, and that you should override `paintComponent`. Functionally, the code is (or should be, anyway) correct in that it does its task. Unless you can give me a reason other than "you should override paintComponent, not paint even though functionally they will act the same in this case", that it is incorrect, then your downvote is IMHO just a bit harsh.

Comment: @VGR I'm using [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org) with the appletviewer for everything because my teacher uses that program to test ours (I use Eclipse when messing around with my personal projects).

Comment: `I DID read the tutorial, which said nothing about JApplets specifically,` - Did  you look at the table of contents? The tutorial covers all the Swing basics. No your painting code is not correct. For one thing you don't invoke super.paint() at the start of your method. You don't create the applet on the Event Dispatch Thread. Again, YOU don't know what the code will do. By leaving it out there can be problems. I didn't originally down vote but I will now (1-) since when you don't follow Swing coding conventions you don't know what problems will occur as the task gets more complicated.

Comment: @camickr Except, the task will not get more complicated in this case. Either way, after moving all the code to an overriden paintComponent method and calling super.paint(), it still does not work. I didn't originally call super.paint() because in every other project I have worked on in Swing, it worked just fine set up exactly how it is. As for my not creating it on the EDT, I believe that is abstracted into the IDE when I right click on the class and click run applet. But I digress. Whatever problem I am having has nothing to do with my not following commonly accepted conventions in this case

Comment: `after moving all the code to an overriden paintComponent method and calling super.paint(), it still does not work.` - you invoke super.?? on the method you are overriding. `I believe that is abstracted into the IDE` - no it isn't. What happens when you run it in the AppletViewer as I did successfully.  It only executes on the EDT if you specify it properly. 'I didn't originally call super.paint()` - Again YOU don't know what that does. It make work for simple code but not for more complex code.

Comment: You apparently are not willing to learn so why do you even ask questions. Until a problem is solved you don't know what the issue is. So code properly. I already stated the code works fine for me. So maybe in your environment or IDE taking shortcuts is causing problems. Did you even think to test your applet without custom painting. Does is show a JLabel? Or is the problem strictly related to custom painting.

Comment: I know what calling super.paint does - it calls the specified method in the base class - if that is what you are hinting at me "not knowing". I clicked the class that extends JApplet and clicked "Run Applet". I am using the BlueJ IDE, which is basically for beginners so I assumed it was automatically performed by the IDE. I am open to learning, but I need more to go off of than "this is wrong" to learn. You told me the "code works fine for you," so I cannot see how I coded improperly... No, it doesn't show a JLabel because the whole point of the program is to display a few polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved this by experimenting around. For whatever reason, the call to g.fillPolygon(Polygon p) was not working, but when I called g.fillPolygon(poly_1_x, poly_1_y, num_recto_points); it worked properly.